# How do I overcome an "Insufficient winsock resources" message that prevents PS Get-ADUser from running

Tags: powershell, remoting

My account is a domain admin, I often log onto a particular server in our network (not the DC), and until recently I could query AD with PS commands, e.g.

```
Get-ADUser crm.webserver -Properties *
```

and I would see the PS message,

```
'Creating a new session for implicit remoting of "Get-ADUser" command...',
```

followed by the results I wanted to see, in this case the properties of the user. But recently the same PS message has **not** been followed by the results I wanted, but instead I see,

```
'Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation.  
    + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (crm.webserver:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser  
    + PSComputerName: dc01.wxyz.dom'
```

Can anyone tell me what likely has gone wrong and point me in the right direction to fix it?

Comment: This is going to be better asked on ServerFault. This error message means you can't open up a socket to connect because they are all in use. This is going to be an Operating System issue rather than a PowerShell code issue. Something has gone wrong on your server, something is likely repeatedly opening connections and not closing them.

Comment: Can I or someone move the question to ServerFault or do I just re-ask it?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157231/how-do-i-move-an-existing-question-i-wrote-from-stack-overflow-to-server-fault